# Generic use of Accounts Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, single-sign-on, acaccount, acaccountstore

I'd like to use the `Accounts Framework` in my app to take advantage of `OAuth` for `Single Sign-On`. What I found in the Apple's documentation regarding the [Accounts Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/index.html#other) is that the account types to use the framework with are limited to `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `Sina Weibo` and `Tencent Weibo`.

I don't want to integrate my app with any social network, I just want to handle user's credentials with `OAuth` for `SSO`. I don't want users having to provide their `Facebook`/`Twitter` account credentials for this (if they have...). Is there any way to achieve this? It would be something like creating and account for my app and store the credentials for it, but looks like iOS SDK does not allow to create accounts for custom or generic account types, is there any alternative?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does anybody have an answer for this?

Comment: Did you find anything out yet about that? Having the same problem currently.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832821/5746918