# Keychain Sharing with watchOS 2 - All about project settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, watchos-2

I am using Xcode 7.0 (7A220), targeting iOS 9.0 and watchOS 2.0.

I haven't gotten keychain sharing to work in a watchOS 2 app of my own, but it works in [this example project](https://github.com/NatashaTheRobot/watchkit), which is part of my question.

There is a good talk from NatashaTheRobot ([here](https://realm.io/news/architecting-app-apple-watch-natashatherobot/)) where she goes over keychain sharing with watchOS.([Working code from github here](https://github.com/NatashaTheRobot/watchkit)), see for yourself that her iOS app and watch app are able to share via keychain in the simulator.

Here's what I have done to her project and it still works:

- Removed the access group string from the KeychainItemWrapper init method. This makes sense because the simulator isn't code signed and the [access group gets deleted in KeychainItemWrapper initWithIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html) (checkout the comment in initWithIdentifier:)
- Removed the identifier string from KeychainItemWrapper initWithIdentifier in both view controllers
- Removed the keychain-access-groups key from both entitlements that specifies a keychain access group key

You can remove these three things and keychain sharing still works in the simulator for this project. Why? Shouldn't entitlements at *least* be necessary?

The thing that finally breaks this project is changing the development team/provisioning profile, which makes me think project settings are the real key to this issue.

In my own project I have added a watchOS 2 extension, added the keychain sharing capability to both targets, added appropriate access groups even with my bundle seed ID, I have tried creating separate provisioning profiles for the iOS app, watchkit app, and watchkit extension. I'm sure I am forgetting things I've already tried, I have been attempting to solve this for about a week to no avail. What am I missing?

[Apple's docs on creating capabilities are not super specific on project settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html). It says to click and turn on capabilities in the project. Done that.

[Apple's other docs on generic keychain use didn't clear it up for me either](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3). They have a project with 2 targets that share a keychain, but as far as I can tell my project settings and theirs aren't significantly different.

[This answer goes over the useyourloaf article from 2010 on keychain sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793271/keychain-group-access-to-share-data-between-my-existing-applications), but like I mentioned before, it seems like the simulator completely ignores those keychain access group identifiers.

I keep thinking there must be something obvious I have missed throughout all of this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since watchOS 2.0 it is not possible to share a keychain item between the watch and its paired device.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5938

Comment: Thanks for bringing some closure to that issue. It drove me insane for about a week!