# iOS: Login from other app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I have two apps developed by me.
I want to LOGIN in my "A" app from my "B" app's credentials.
So when user click on button "Login from B" then it should login from "B" and if app "B" is not already logged in then it shall open the "B" app and then User needs to login and then minimise the "B" app and return it to "A" app.

Example:- Login from Facebook.

How to do it?

Comment: You can use App Groups and Shared extension to achieve above scenario. you can go through this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2311/_index.html

also this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793271/keychain-group-access-to-share-data-between-my-existing-applications

Comment: @CodeChanger :- Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

When you open the other app please pass the login credentials along with the deep link schema or if you have a login session pass login session as a param in deep link schema.